# IE9 not showing every other <hr> tag inside asp repeater's separator template

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I've a horizontal rule (HR) tag inside the separator template of an Asp.Net repeater control. For some strange reason, Internet Explorer 9 displays the 2nd, 4th .. horizontal rules but not the 1st, 3rd ...ones. I don't have this problem in Firefox and Google Chrome. Here is the page with the problem:

http://alt.thedominion.ca/TheBrokerAdvantage/Broker-Search-Results.aspx?postalCode=M5H3B9

Nowhere in my CSS files do I have a rule to hide every other HR.

Please help

Comment: I viewed with both Chrome and IE9. The result is same. No invisible HR !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't repro your problem, although I do have IE10 but it might be because you have the markup:

```
<tr><td class="basic"><a class="contact" target="_blank" href="http://www.bfl87.ca">www.bfl87.ca</a></td></tr>
```

that isn't inside a table so is invalid and might be causing problems. Try fixing this and the other problems that show up here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Falt.thedominion.ca%2FTheBrokerAdvantage%2FBroker-Search-Results.aspx%3FpostalCode%3DM5H3B9&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I've noticed the problem goes away if the HTML markup validates correctly. E.g.                                         http://alt.thedominion.ca/TheBrokerAdvantage/Broker-Search-Results.aspx?postalCode=N0A1C0